# PHP session variables lost in Firefox 46.0.1+Windows, but works with Firefox 46.0.1+Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, jquery, session, firefox

I have 2 test scripts: `session_test.php` and `session_write.php`.
The `session_test.php` script is loading the `session_write.php` using an jQuery load function. 
The script runs fine in Ubuntu14.04+Firefox 46.0.1, but it doesn't add
the data session variable in Windows 8.1 or 10 with Firefox 46.0.1.
Windows 10 + Chrome, Edge and Opera work fine.

Can someone help me to fix this issue?

`session_test.php:`

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['test']= 'testing';

?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>website title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="merken" id="merken"/> Merken box
  <div id="div_session_write"></div>

  <script>
  $('.merken').click( function () {
        var merk = 'test';

        var url = "session_write.php?data="+encodeURIComponent(merk);
        console.log(url);
        $('#div_session_write').load(url);

       location.reload(true);
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

`session_write.php:`

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
    $_SESSION['data'] = $_GET['data'];
}
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

**update [7-July-2016]**
This issue is posted at developer.mozilla.org as a bug and is
reproduced by the developers of mozilla. They are working on
a solution.

**update [13-July-2016]**
The solution that works for me is:

```
$('#div_session_write').load( url, function() {
  self.location = self.location;
});
```

The solution was provided by the Firefox developers,
as they found it to be a timing issue.

Comment: check in your browser is cookie is enabled or not? if not enable cookie and then try

Comment: It works for me. (Firefox 46.0.1 + Win10)

Comment: @BindeshPandya Cookies are enabled. I can see the phpSessionId in the cookie.

Comment: @SandroMarques can you give the output on your screen? Only the first line.

Comment: @Deepfreeze array(1) { ["test"]=> string(7) "testing" }

Comment: Ok, so it's also not working for you. The output under Linux Firefox, Windows + Edge,IE11,Chrome and Opera is:   `array(2) { ["test"]=> string(7) "testing" ["data"]=> string(4) "test" } `

Answer (score -1):

avoid using
console.log(url);
location.reload(true);
and then the data session varaible is running

Comment: Removing `console.log(url)` didn't help. `location.reload(true)` is now replaced by `self.location = self.location`. Still same effect under Windows 10 + Firefox 46.0.1.

Answer (score -3):

.ajax function is better.

session_test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test']= 'testing';
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>website title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="merken" id="merken"/> Merken box
  <div id="div_session_write"></div>

  <script>
  $('.merken').click( function () {
        var merk = 'test';

        var url = "session_write.php?data="+encodeURIComponent(merk);
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          success: function(response) {
            $('#div_session_write').html(response);
          }
        });
       //location.reload(true);
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

session_write.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
    $_SESSION['data'] = $_GET['data'];
}
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```